# How can I initiate the current httpcontext when accessing an asp.net library from a service?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, httpcontext

I have an asp.net project that's compiled on a server.  On that same server I have a windows service that's running methods referenced from the asp.net .dll.

Everything works fine except for when the httpcontext.current object needs to be accessed.

I'm fairly certain that the cause of the .current being null is that it's referencing the shared library without an actual instance of the site running.  In a previous version of the service I was able to find a workaround in asp.net by not using the context, however that is now a last resort as much of the architecture of the site has changed.

Is there anyway to create an instance of the site and simulate a current httpcontext for the purposes of the service?

Comment: There is no HttpContext, because you are not in a http context. There is no ongoing request and response, and you don't even have a website as far as the windows service is concerned. How would you expect it to work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.NET framework instantiates and manages the HTTP context and  outside of ASP.NET, this will always be null.  You'd have to dig into the framework to figure out how to create it, but honestly, it wouldn't be worth it...

However, could you reconfigure your HttpContext references to point to HTTpcontextbase?  If you did, HttpContextBase is a base class and can be inherited by anyone.  Very easily, you could create a  custom one to achieve what you want.  You can even create your own static to wrap HttpContext.Current, refer to this static in the app, and to this static in the service (but have the service initially instantiate it).

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'm thinking about adding a webservice to the asp.net project and trying to pull data that way.  Is that something you might recommend?

Comment: HttpContext.Current is available for web requests so yes that would work.  My solution was if you have no other alternative and needed to do something offline.  Using a web service as @Patricker suggested would work.

Comment: Ok, I ended up adding a webservice and it all worked out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not from the windows service.  I think the proper way to do this would be to create a webservice that handles anything you need asp.net for and call that webservice from your windows service.

Also, if you post some of the code that is relying on httpcontext.current it might be possible to find alternatives (assuming that they really don't rely on the request/response actions).